# The view rest.views.submitreq didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

i am new in django.I have facing a problem with the form validation.

the error is  **ValueError at /app/rest/submitreq_val/
The view rest.views.submitreq didn't return an HttpResponse object.**

this is my forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

 from request.models import Request

 class SubreqForm(forms.Form):
    request = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = forms.CharField()
    sub_category = forms.CharField()
```

this is my views.py for my form validation

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
 from request.models import Request
 from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.template import Context,RequestContext, loader
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.core.context_processors import csrf
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 from rest.forms import SubreqForm

 def submitreq(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    sub_req = SubreqForm(request.POST)

    if sub_req.is_valid():
        success = True
        request = sub_req.cleaned_data['request']
        category = sub_req.cleaned_data['category']
        sub_category = sub_req.cleanded_data['sub_category']
else:
    sub_req = SubreqForm()
    ctx = {'sub_req': sub_req}
    return render_to_response("rest/test.html",ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is my template...

```
{% block title %}
  Test
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form action = "" method = "post">
  {{sub_req.as_p}}
  <input type = "submit" value = "send">
{% endblock %}
```

now please help me to solve this error.

Comment: First clarify what is `{{sub_req.as_p}}`. you want to display those field which you have created in forms.py `{{sub_req.request}}` or `{{sub_req.category }}` like that and second you didn't write in forms.py file `request = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet's indentation is broken so it's hard to say for sure, but it looks like you're only returning a response for a GET request. The other branch doesn't return explicitly, which means it returns `None` instead of a HttpResponse object.

Also, this line:

```
request = sub_req.cleaned_data['request']
```

shadows the HttpRequest object passed to your view. This makes no difference at the moment but you will probably need the HttpRequest object later in this branch too.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this and check it is working

```
sub_req = SubreqForm()
ctx = {'sub_req': sub_req}
context = RequestContext(request, ctx)
return render_to_response("rest/test.html", context_instance=context)
```